# How to define whether a spring security filter should be called or not

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have many beans on my applicationContext.xml but I don't want to call all of them. Before calling a bean there are some complex rules that define whether they should be called or not and I'm not able to modify their source code.
Are there some kind of special "matching" rule that I can implement?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security has a vast amount of configuration options. However, without more information it is very hard to figure out what exactly you are trying to do.

Some hints:

- All Spring Security filters are instances of `javax.servlet.Filter`.
- However, they are usually not declared directly as filters in your webapp, but called by `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy` (which is a `javax.servlet.Filter`, too).
- `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy` organizes filters in instances of `org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain`.
- There may be more that one `SecurityFilterChain`. The chains are matched to requests using `org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher`.

Long story short, you might be able to create multiple `SecurityFilterChain` instances and implement the "complex logic" in `RequestMatcher` instances. The way to wire everything up depends heavily on your current setup.